# Rails - How to use Joins the Correct Way

Tags: join, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have two models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :event_occurrences, dependent: :destroy
end

class EventOccurence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

The `EventOccurrence` model is used *only* when the main `Event` is recurring.  For example, let's say I have the following events:

```
  =>Event(:id => 1, :name => "Picnic", :start_time => "2014-01-02 13:45", :end_time => 2014-01-02 14:45")

  =>Event(:id => 2, :name => "Meeting", :start_time => 2014-01-03 13:00", :end_time => 2014-01-03 14:00")

  =>EventOccurrence(id: 44, :event_id => 1, :date => "2014-01-09 13:45")
```

Thus, the `EventOccurence` object above is a one-time occurence of the "Picnic", which should  occur 2 times (on January 2nd, January 9th) in total.

However, **I cannot get all 3 events** to render at the same time.  I've tried:

```
@events = Event.all.count
=> 2 

@events = Event.all.includes(:event_occurrences).count
=> 2

@events = Event.all.joins(:event_occurrences).count
=> 1
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  **My guess** is that I have my models set up incorrectly for handling recurring events.  If this is the case, I would surely appreciate some feedback on a better way to store these occurrences in a join table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I think you are using it wrong. Really you have only 3 Events, let's say, and each event have may occurrences. So, to each event you can ask for its occurrences. Like

```
@event.event_occurrences.each do |occurrence|
    occurrence.date #for example
do
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, for a "single" event without any additional occurrences, should I still store it in `event_occurrences` table?

Comment: In the way you modeled it, yes, and anyways is the way, I think, is supposed to work

Comment: Ah, ok.  So, just to clarify: should I move my `:start_time`, `:end_time` fields into the `EventOccurrence` model instead, since those will be variable and will be changing with each new occurrence?

Comment: Yes, all the info that belongs only to each occurrence, should be moved to the event_occurrence model. Good luck